# TwinCat Run Mode failing to start with adswarning 4131

Tags: twincat

I am trying to start a twincat project on my pc in order to debug it. I've disabled the EtherCAT device and isolated a CPU on my windows 10 with an 8-core ADM processor. After trying to start the run mode, I get a fatal error on the target system. With following message:

> 'TwinCat System' (10000): Sending ams command >> Init4
>   RTime: Start Interrupt: Ticker started >> AdsWarning: 4131 (0x1023, RTIME: Intel CPU required) << failed!

I've searched the internet and am not able to find a solution to this problem. There seems to be little information about this. Anyone of you having an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, just in case anyone else would come across the same problem: make sure when you isolate a CPU to emulate the PLC on that you also check it as the default one to be used. Just isolating isn't enough, you have to explicitly indicate the one to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer appears to be right there in the message: `Intel CPU required`, but you stated you're trying to run it on an ADM (I assume AMD) processor.

Comment: Hi Jim That is also what I thought, but I know someone who is able to run it on his computer which also uses an amd processor. It just feels strange that because the PLC uses an intel processor, that you cannot debug offline using any kind of processor...